# JNI + DefineClass + class cross reference

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I've come across with a jni problem. There are two Java classes

```
public class C {
    public static final D D_REFERENCE = new D();
    
    public static void printer(){
        System.out.println("C check");
    }
```

and

```
public class D {
    public static final C C_REFERENCE = new C();
    
    public static void printer(){
        System.out.println("D check");
    }
}
```

When I try to load these classes using code below nothing happens.

```
loadedClass = jniEnv->DefineClass(classtoload, system_loader, jniEnv->GetByteArrayElements(binaryClass, 0), num_bytes);
```

loadedClass not NULL but I can't call java method printer()

```
methodid = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(loadedClass, "printer", "()V");
```

When I remove `public static final D D_REFERENCE = new D();` and `public static final C C_REFERENCE = new C();` from classes, everything is ok, and method `printer()` is called correctly. So the question is - is it possible to use DefineClass on classes with a cross reference, and if so, how?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your test code? Do you load both classes in succession or just one before you try to instantiate C?

Comment: The order of loading doesn't matter. I can load the first class

Comment: See answer. I recreated your situation and solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define or load a class, is not initialized yet. According to the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), initialization happens when one of the following occurs:

> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

Your call to `GetStaticMethodID` causes the initialization of class C, which in turn requires the initialization of `D_REFERENCE`, which causes the instantiation of a new D object, which causes the initialization of class D.

If you add basic error checking to your code the problem is immediately obvious:

```
jmethodID C_printer = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(loadedClass, "printer", "()V");
if (jniEnv->ExceptionOccurred()) {
    jniEnv->ExceptionDescribe();
    return 1;
}
```

This prints:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: D
    at C.<clinit>(C.java:2)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: D
```

where `<clinit>` is the internal class initialization method.

If you also `DefineClass` D *before* accessing any of the members of C or creating an instance, the initialization process will see that D has been loaded and can continue as normal.

And just because I was curious: the [Java class initialization process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) tolerates recursive initializations:

> If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for initialization. Release LC and complete normally.